# Invalid Keystore format - after converting to JKS from pfx

Tags: java, pfx, jks, mutual-authentication

I am on Java 1.7.0_60.
I have a pfx keystore which I converted to JKS keystore using below:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mypfx.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore myjks.jks -deststoretype jks
```

Now when I use this JKS keystore in my code to load the KeyStore object I get `IOException: Invalid Keystore format` at line#3 in below snippet:

```
InputStream is =  HttpTester.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myjks.jks");
KeyStore identityKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");  
identityKeyStore.load(inputStream, CERT_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
```

I also verified that the newly created `myjks.jks` keystore is not corrupted by doing this and was able to open up just fine

```
keytool -v -list -keystore myjks.jks
```

I am trying to do a mutual two-way SSL authentication which is why I am on this version of Java and also be able to deploy it onto a Websphere 8.5 server which only supports 1.7.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough information. How did you do the import? Can `keytool` read the keystore file, e.g. to list content?

Comment: I used this command `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mypfx.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore myjks.jks -deststoretype jks`

Comment: Edit the question and add that command to *clarify* the question. Also verify that `keytool` can read the keystore, so add the command and output used to *test* the keystore.

Comment: @Andreas edited. Yes `keytool` can read the keystore as well.

Comment: Since you didn't specify any password on the `keytool` command-lines, the keystore doesn't have a store password, so pass `null` to the `load` method.

Comment: @Andreas `'keytool -v -list -keystore myjks.jks` always prompts for Password before showing me the contents of it so the password is not `null` for sure. Also during `jks` creation`keytool -importkeystore` prompted me to enter `destination password`. I am thinking if I can achieve the same conversion using `openssl`

Comment: You can't achieve the same conversion using `openssl`, since it doesn't support the `jks` format. You could of course instead try using the `mypfx.pfx` file directly, by using `KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12")`

Comment: Using pkcs12 worked and surprisingly using 'jks' worked as well when I tried in a different version of eclipse.

Comment: Different version of Eclipse shouldn't have mattered, but different version of Java definitely could have. Did your other Eclipse perhaps use an older Java version? Anyway, since problem is no longer reproducible, you should just delete this question.